# Связка aiogram и discord

Tags: python, aiogram, discord, discord.py

Есть телеграм бот на aiogram. Суть в том, что хендлер должен отправить команду в дискорд боту midjorney и получить ответ. Подскажите кейс. С discord вообще не сталкивался никогда. Прошу не пинать. Нужно разворачивать бота дискорд? Код должен быть асинхронным. Python.

Comment: Да, проще всего будет сделать это через бота в дискорде. О реализации кода у меня есть отдельное руководство, можете почитать здесь: https://github.com/denisnumb/discord-py-guide/blob/main/discord-py.md#%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8E-%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B8-discord-py

Comment: У тебя получилось это сделать? Можем пообщаться?